# Error include(php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory Yii Version 1.1.22 + S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, yii, yii1.x

I'm trying to put/get an s3 object using  Yii 1.1.22  and AWS PHP v3 , and when I try to upload an image to s3 I'm getting below error :

```
include(php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

stack trace

```
[error] [php] include(php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (/xxxx/framework/yii/framework/YiiBase.php:463)
yii stack trace:
#0 unknown(0): spl_autoload_call()
#1 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(151): method_exists()
#2 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(113): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->settle()
#3 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->resolve()
#4 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(156): callHandler()
#5 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#6 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run()
#7 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(123): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->tick()
#8 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler->execute()
#9 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#10 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(267): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#11 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#12 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#13 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Coroutine.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#14 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Coroutine->GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#15 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#16 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#17 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Coroutine.php(85): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#18 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(273): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Coroutine->wait()
#19 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#20 /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#21 /xxxx/vendors/aws/Aws/AwsClientTrait.php(59): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#22 /xxxx/vendors/aws/Aws/AwsClientTrait.php(78): Aws\S3\S3Client->execute()
#23 /xxxx/protected/extensions/s3/ES3.php(125): Aws\S3\S3Client->__call()
#24 /xxxx/protected/components/Uploader.php(97): ES3->upload()
#25 /xxxx/protected/modules/account/controllers/UserController.php(619): Uploader->upload()
#26 /xxxx/protected/modules/account/controllers/UserController.php(411): UserController->saveUser()
#27 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): UserController->actionEditUser()
#28 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#29 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/web/CController.php(286): UserController->runAction()
#30 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/web/CController.php(265): UserController->runActionWithFilters()
#31 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): UserController->run()
#32 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#33 /xxxx/framework/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#34 /xxxx/index.php(36): CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/_pfpg_CVWaHvEhl-5MEij5PiF9oCmnFPK6yNHIX7sqetYnfGY_vcsum=b4b2ef23eeb23074c51a8c6631b491861541198cd0ea11492713cb2cd6bfce10
in /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php (151)
in /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php (113)
in /xxxx/vendors/aws/GuzzleHttp/Promise/Promise.php (203)
```

I'm using below code to upload :

```php
$result = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => '',
    'Key'    => 'ogo_1070.png ',
]);
```

and my s3 config is :

```php
$arrS3Config = [
    'region' => ( getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') == 'dr' ) ? 'eu-central-1' : 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
];
```

Can any one help me how trace this error at least

Thanks

Comment: How do you include AWS sdk into the project and how do you add its autoloading?

Comment: did you try composer update?

Comment: Do you use composer autoloader (`require 'vendor/autoload.php'`)?